# Delete cell in which address is in another cell using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete a cell using an excel macro where the address to that cell is text in another cell. I need the code to be very simple as I am almost a complete beginner.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of how your data is arranged?

Answer (score 0):

simple enough?

```
Sub Whipe()
Dim RAddress As Range, RAdrCell As Range
Dim RWhipe As Range, RWhipeCell As Range

    Set RAddress = Range([A1], [F6]) ' range containing the addresses
    Set RWhipe = Range([A7], [F12])  ' range containing data to be whiped

    For Each RWhipeCell In RWhipe.Cells
        For Each RAdrCell In RAddress.Cells
            If RWhipeCell.Address(False, False) = RAdrCell Then
                RWhipeCell = ""
            End If
        Next RAdrCell
    Next RWhipeCell
End Sub
```

before
[image]

after
[image]